# Ошибка 500.19 IIS 10 Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows-10, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

Прошу помощи в запуске приложения созданного на asp.net target framework 4.5.2, сервер - локальный IIS(не IIS Express).
Обновили винду на пк и перестало запускаться приложение. В службе windows 10 можно установить IIS 10 и там можно выбрать asp.net 3.5 и asp.net 4.8.

Приложение с такими настройками сервера не запускается и выдает ошибку 500.19. По советам на форумах были выданы права доступа на папку, в которой размещено приложение, к аккаунту IIS_IUSRS к всему приложению, через iis.

Ошибка 500.19 ругается на путь к web.config.
Пытался  выявить проблему в web.config. Если удалить секцию `<location>`, то приложение пытается запустится, но не отвечает.

Консольные командлеты dism/online/enable-feature/all/featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 ничего не меняет.
На сколько я помню, то на прошлой windows 10 можно было в службе IIS выбирать asp.net 4.5, поскольку все работало без проблем.

Будут ли у кого мысли?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо проверить возможность роутинга. Мне понадобилось установить пакет url-rewriter 2.После чего приложение запустилось. Эта штука нужна для возможности создавать url из web.config.

Также мне требовалось установить для своего приложения (в пуле приложений) Identity(находится в дополнительных настройках) для своей учетной записи. Данная настройка запускает приложение под вашей учетной записью.